# How can I create a dataframe from a for loop and add a column that doesn't get overwritten?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, dataframe

I am pulling daily stock data from the Alpha Vantage API, which returns JSON. Because I'm pulling data for multiple companies, I created a for loop so I don't have to repeat the process for each company (the two companies are 'zm' and 'sq' in the example below).

The for loop should create a dataframe that appends each company's data to the bottom. The problem I'm facing is that when I create a column to show the company symbol, it overwrites the previous company's symbol each time it iterates through the loop. **How can I add to the company symbol column without overwriting the previous company's symbol?**

```
ticks = ['zm','sq']
df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in ticks:
    response = requests.request("GET", url="https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol="+i+"&outputsize=full&apikey=DEMOKEY")
    jsd = json.loads(response.text)
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(jsd['Time Series (Daily)']).T)
    df['symbol'] = i

df
```

This gets me close, but in the column I created called "symbol," every row says 'sq' instead of the 'zm' rows saying 'zm'. The 'zm' rows were overwritten with 'sq' the second time through the loop.

```
Date    1. open 2. high 3. low  4. close    5. volume   symbol
2020-07-29  255.5500    259.9300    251.1500    252.3900    3260312 sq
2020-07-28  252.7000    258.9100    251.3200    252.1800    3366216 sq
2020-07-27  249.2800    252.9700    246.2200    252.3300    3328563 sq
2020-07-24  246.2000    250.2100    237.2000    246.5600    4303198 sq
2020-07-23  260.8400    264.9000    249.2100    251.5000    4589358 sq
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2015-11-25  12.1200 12.4000 11.8500 11.9000 3583421 sq
2015-11-24  12.0000 12.2300 11.5200 12.0200 4714682 sq
2015-11-23  13.0000 13.1500 12.1000 12.1200 5172246 sq
2015-11-20  13.9200 14.0500 12.5000 12.8500 16550328    sq
2015-11-19  11.2000 14.7800 9.0000  13.0700 47466050    sq
```

Is there a way to do this (or a better way to achieve my goal)?

Comment: are you sure only company symbol is overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
ticks = ['zm','sq']
df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in ticks:
    response = requests.request("GET", url="https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol="+i+"&outputsize=full&apikey=DEMOKEY")
    jsd = json.loads(response.text)
    temp_df =pd.DataFrame(jsd['Time Series (Daily)']).T
    temp_df['symbol'] = i
    df = df.append(temp_df)
   
df
```